# Copy list item from Prod to Dev using Powershell or Server Object model

Tags: powershell, migration, object-model, list-item

I'm looking for the best way, either throught Powershell or the Object Model, to copy a list item from Production to Dev. The lists are identical, I just have one item that is causing an error in an operation that I cannot reproduce in Dev.

I do not want to export the list as a template w/ content.

Comment: I would check out Chris O'Brien's Content Deployment Wizard - it's a third party tool, but a great way to move content between farms.  https://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks! We have paid for a Metalogix tool but it can't even migrate at the list item level (I've been told)